# Is it possible to change how the record is displayed in report depending on a value of a field?

Tags: ms-access, report

I want to create a report in MS Access database, that would display records from single table, but I want it to change the way every record is displayed depending on a value of certain field of each record.

As an example, let's say I have a db to manage items available in a library, i.e. books, e-books, audiobooks. I want to prepare a report, that would allow printing items borrowed today, but depending on item type (printed book, e-book, audiobook), I want do display different set of fields of every matching record.

What I mean is that I want to display different *details view* for a record, depending on it's type. I don't want to change per field appearance of a record, but record as a whole, e.g. changing height of a whole "record frame" in a report to match how much data will be displayed. To describe it some other way - I want to use different template for different types of records (different templates used in same report at the same time if different types of *books* were borrowed).

Is it possible to do that in MS Access? I am working with it for the first time after around 20 years :/

Comment: You can have expressions in textboxes or VBA code that can control display of textboxes or Conditional Formatting that changes color of textboxes. Your question is quite broad and really not suited for SO since there is no specific issue and no code to analyze.

Comment: Maybe reread [ask] as your question is missing some essentials. How to change a record is displayed targets the format? Then`Conditional Formatting`is your friend. If target is data, e.g. one field in record should display the location for a printed book, but the url for an e-book (different fields in db), you can use union query.

Comment: Maybe indeed my description was too general, so I've added another section with a more detailed info that I want to be able to create different templates for each type, but to be able to use them at the same time in single report.

Comment: Sizeing controls heigth is done automatic if you enable controls CanShrink/Grow properties. Options missing in`Conditional Formatting`may be done in reports format event. Show some example data/formatting (and again, a visit to the help center on asking is recommended).